# Using GPU Shared Memory : A check on my understanding

Tags: cuda, double, gpu-shared-memory

I have a GTX Titan that has 49152 bytes/block of shared memory.  I'm trying to solve ~9000 coupled ODE's and would like to store these ~9000 concentrations, which are `double`s, in shared memory in order to calculate the rate of change of each concentration.

So I'd just like to affirm that this is NOT possible since a `double` is 8 bytes and 49152/8 = 6144.  Right?

Comment: You could have multiple blocks.

Comment: Each of the 9000 threads needs to have access to these 9000 doubles in order to compute its respective rate of change, so it's no good to have some of the concentrations on one block on one MP and the rest on another block on another. (Assuming I am understanding how this works correctly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. You cannot simultaneously store 9000 `double` quantities in shared memory that is accessible by a single threadblock (i.e. in a single SM).

Answer (score -1):

You can use register file too! That part can have important fraction of shared mem per SM. Private variables each on register space of a core/streaming unit can be used in a "swap in local memory" manner to communicate with other cores in the same block. Register swapping could compensate for 48kB shared mem per sm for the titan.

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate, please?  It's been a while since I've worked on this CUDA stuff.  I'm still trying to figure out exactly what the register is (seems like low-latency memory allocated specifically per thread) and how I can use it.

Comment: Its similar to a cpu-register(AX,BX,CX) but with an addressable access property so there may be thousands per smx(or 192 cores).

Comment: Registers and local memory are, by definition, thread scope. It is impossible to use either as a mechanism to pass data between threads. Any suggestion otherwise is plain wrong.

Comment: Registers can be 'shared' between threads with warp shuffle instructions. Not clear if that would benefit this application, though.

Comment: My HD7870 has a 256kB private vector registers per compute unit and its bandwidth is 768 GB/s per compute unit. Each compute unit having 64 processing units. Plus, it has a LDS(local data store, shared between processing units in a compute unit) of size 64kB per compute unit and has 128GB/s bandwidth per compute unit. So you are saying titan has only single thing that is used for both registers and local memory?